# Different between " ; " and " && " in bash

Tags: bash

I've been doing lots of Linux based stuff with my time and I know that the `;` is used to separate commands, and `&&` runs command after the previous one is done.

But if anyone more knowledgeable then me can explain the difference between the two, that would be nice.

Here's a simple example:

```
whoami ; hostname
```

```
whoami && hostname
```

Comment: The former the second command will run/execute regardless if the first command before the `;` succeeded e.g. it returns an exit status of `1`. the latter is the opposite, the second command will run/execute ONLY if the first command succeeded e.g. it has an exit status of `0`, sinde `&&` means `AND`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`;` will execute the second command whether or not the first returns without error.
`&&` is the bash `AND` logical operator, and will execute the second command only if the first returns succesfully without error.

The success of a command is determined by its [exit status](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.htmlhttps://).